# Getting response in question marks format

Tags: android, web-services, utf-8

Below is my response that I am getting from server

> 1|1,1,???? ???? ???????? ????|1,2,???? ???? ???? ??? ????????
>   ????|2,3,?????? ???????? ????? ????|2,4,?????? ???????? ?????
>   ?????????????|2,5,?????? ???????? ????? ?????? ?????????|3,6,??????
>   ???? ????? ????|3,7,?????? ???? ???????? ????????|3,8,???? ??????
>   ?????? ????????|3,9,???? ?????? ??? ?????????|4,15,?????? ????? ??????
>   ????????|5,10,???????????|6,11,??????????? ????????
>   ????|6,12,???????????? ???? ????? ????|6,13,?????  ??? ??? ?????
>   ????|7,14,????|7,16,????

I want to convert it into readable format.

Comment: share db structure & webservice

Comment: This sounds like perhaps it is an encoding problem somewhere.

Comment: did you Encoded that; ?

Comment: @nihal_softy that is not json string

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes you are right. there Might be some encoding issue

Comment: You can't fix that. It isn't like decoding an encryption. That is an encoding issue, unless the server returns it by intent. If the latter is false, it is an encoding issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decoded the response

```
String resultData = URLDecoder.decode(resultData, "UTF-8");
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is server side problem. May server text is not only English. I face this problem a few years later. So, try to make column Collation "utf8_bin"